# HTML forms auto caps lock

Tags: javascript, html, forms, key

Is there a way to make it so that in an html form, someone types something, and it automatically makes it a capitol letter, like in a software key code input, I would like there to automatically be a dash inserted after every five characters, but not after the last one, meaning that when someone types:

`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

it will automatically be entered in to the form in real time as:

`XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX`

Is there a way to achieve this in real time? Here is my current code for the form:

```
<form name="key" autocomplete="off">
Key: <input type="text" name="key" maxlength="23"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="check(this.form)" value="  Submit  "/>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
function check(form)
{
if (form.key.value == "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX")
{
window.open('URL')
}
else
{
alert ("Invalid Key")
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: do you want it in real time or on submit ?

Comment: I would like to do it in real time. @BabyAzerty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not optimal at all, but it works !

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function(){
    var isCorrect = false;
    $('#key_id').on('keyup',function() {
        $(this).val(function(i, text) {
            text = text.toUpperCase();
            if (text.length < 5) {
                isCorrect = false;
                return text;
            } else if (text.length >= 5 && text.length < 11 && (text.split("-").length - 1) < 1) {
                isCorrect = false;
                return text.substr(0,5) + '-' + text.substr(5,5);
            } else if (text.length >= 11 && text.length < 17 && (text.split("-").length - 1) < 2) {
                isCorrect = false;
                text = text.replace(/-/g, '');
                return text.substr(0,5) + '-' + text.substr(5,5) + '-' + text.substr(10,5);
            } else if (text.length >= 17 && text.length < 23 && (text.split("-").length - 1) < 3) {
                isCorrect = false;
                text = text.replace(/-/g, '');
                return text.substr(0,5) + '-' + text.substr(5,5) + '-' + text.substr(10,5) + '-' + text.substr(15,5);
            } else if (text.length >= 23) {
                isCorrect = true;
                text = text.replace(/-/g, '');
                return text.substr(0,5) + '-' + text.substr(5,5) + '-' + text.substr(10,5) + '-' + text.substr(15,5);
            } else {
                isCorrect = false;
                return text;
            }
        });
    });

   $("#my_form").submit(function(){
        if(isCorrect) {
            window.open('URL');
        } else {
            alert('invalid');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

On the event keyup (releasing a key = letter/number), I do :

1. UpperCase
2. Return the text normally if less than 5 char
3. Return the text with '-' if more than 5 char but less than 10+1 char (the +1 is because we added '-'). Else return the text normally if already added the '-'
4. Return the text with 2 '-' if more than 10+1 char but less than 15+2 char (because 2 '-'). Else return the text normally if already added the 2 '-'.

And so on...

**EDIT :**
Updated code, you will need to use jQuery and put an id to your input `id="key_id"`

**EDIT :**
New code, easier for you to use it. Still needs jQuery (you can do it without, search on StackOverflow how to convert $(id).val() in pure javascript).

http://jsfiddle.net/f8BzW/1/

Comment: Could you include this in my code, so I know how to use it properly? Because it doesn't seem to be working. Also, at the top, where it says #input, do I need to change that to whatever the name of my form is? @BabyAzerty

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound like a complete coding idiot, but at the bottom, is that the function to check if the key is correct? If so, how do I use it? It's different than it was before. @BabyAzerty

Comment: Updated the code, changed how to check the input so it does it in real-time instead of using regex. This time, just add jQuery (in the `<head>`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use css for the capitalization: `text-transform: uppercase;`

And with jquery + this plugin: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#key").mask("xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx");
});
```

check out the demo

So after reading the comments I decided to code it all out in a demo for you.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doppel/v3eLX/#&togetherjs=KgqxizB1Fc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
    <title></title> 
</head>

<body>
    <form name="key" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="key">Key:</label><input type="text" name="key" id="key" style="text-transform:uppercase;" maxlength="23"/>
        <input type="submit" onclick="check(this.form)" id="btn" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        function check(form)
        {
            if (form.key.value == "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX")
                window.open('URL')
            else
                alert ("Invalid Key")
        }

        $("document").ready(function() {
            $("#key").mask("aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa",{placeholder:" "});
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Note you will have to download the plugin and include it like I have or copy the fiddle code.

So as you see I added a label because its proper,
I added an Id to the input to make it easier to select, Note I also added an in-line style to force Uppercase as stated above ^^^^.

Now the script `$("document").ready(function() {`gets jquery ready to be used.

`$("#key").mask("aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa",{placeholder:" "});` This statement selects id key as the target of the function Mask which is the plugin to be called stating that we want a format aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa where a is equal to "letter". Note only "a" and "9" denote alpha and numeric data.  And "{placeholder:" "})" the plugin by default puts underscores as placeholders but I changed it to a space to look more what you want I think.

Comment: I hate to ask for more, but how could I embed this in to my current code? @doppel

Comment: did you post all your code? it looks like your posted only a section. You need to include jquery have you used jquery before? If not this may not be the best choice. If you don't use this you will have to code out a custom function like the other answer.

Comment: I included all of my code. It is not a full page because I am embedding it in my site. I just do not understand how to include this function in my code and correctly call jquery and the plugin and all that other stuff. I don't really know very much when it comes to coding. @doppel

Comment: Okay on that link I posted; under usages, it pretty well tells you how to use it but I will update my answer to try and illustrate that better.

Comment: would you mind post the entire page code as well? or --> www.jsfiddle.net